# Opening various pdfs in Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have been running through tutorials and building a basic Windows 8.1 store app.
the app containes various links through to PDF files that I have stored in an assets folder and have been trying get them to open in windows reader by default...

So far I have one single pdf file that opens perfectly once clicked. But I need this to work across all PDF files and not just the one I have specified in the filetoLaunch variable.

```
(function () {
 "use strict";

 WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/page/page.html", {

     ready: function (element, options) {
         document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("click", launchFile, false);

     }
 });

 var fileToLaunch = "assets\\mypdf.pdf";

 function launchFile() { Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(fileToLaunch).done(
         function (file) {
             Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).done(
                 function (success) {
                     if (success) {
                         WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " launched.", "sample", "status");
                     } else {
                         WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File launch failed.", "sample", "error");
                     }
                 });
         });
 }
```

Basically I can't figure out how to change the filetoLaunch variable to define ALL pdfs and not just that single one.

Any ideas would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your file name in that function.

you just need to give full file path.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="fileLauncher('Database.txt')">Database.txt</button>
<button onclick="fileLauncher('Modules.txt')">Modules.txt</button>
<button onclick="fileLauncher('My_Comments.pdf')">My_Comments.pdf</button>
```

**JS**

```
function fileLauncher(fileName) {

    var fileToLaunch = "Assets\\"+fileName;

     Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(fileToLaunch).done(
            function (file) {
                Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).done(
                    function (success) {
                        if (success) {
                            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " launched.", "sample", "status");
                        } else {
                            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File launch failed.", "sample", "error");
                        }
                    });
            });

}
```